# How to flatten individual pandas dataframes and stack them to achieve a new one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a function which takes in data for a particular year and returns a dataframe.

For example:

**df**

```
year    fruit    license     grade
1946    apple       XYZ        1
1946    orange      XYZ        1
1946    apple       PQR        3
1946    orange      PQR        1
1946    grape       XYZ        2
1946    grape       PQR        1
..
2014    grape       LMN        1
```

Note:
1) a specific license value will exist only for a particular year and only once for a particular fruit (eg. XYZ only for 1946 and only once for apple, orange and grape).
2) Grade values are categorical.

I realize the below function isn't very efficient to achieve its intended goals,
but this is what I am currently working with.

```
def func(df, year):
    #1. Filter out only the data for the year needed

    df_year=df[df['year']==year]
    '''
    2. Transform DataFrame to the form:
              XYZ    PQR    ..     LMN
    apple      1      3             1
    orange     1      1             3
    grape      2      1             1
    Note that 'LMN' is just used for representation purposes. 
    It won't logically appear here because it can only appear for the year 2014.
    '''
    df_year = df_year.pivot(index='fruit',columns='license',values='grade')    

    #3. Remove all fruits that have ANY NaN values 
    df_year=df_year.dropna(axis=1, how="any")

    #4. Some additional filtering

    #5. Function to calculate similarity between fruits
    def similarity_score(fruit1, fruit2):
        agreements=np.sum(  ( (fruit1 == 1) & (fruit2 == 1) ) | \
        (  (fruit1 == 3) & (fruit2 == 3) ))

        disagreements=np.sum(  ( (fruit1 == 1) & (fruit2 == 3) ) |\
        (  (fruit1 == 3) & (fruit2 == 1) ))

        return (( (agreements-disagreements) /float(len(fruit1)) ) +1)/2)

    #6. Create Network dataframe
    network_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source','Target','Weight'])

    for i,c in enumerate(combinations(df_year,2)):
        c1=df[[c[0]]].values.tolist()
        c2=df[[c[1]]].values.tolist()
        c1=[item for sublist in c1 for item in sublist]
        c2=[item for sublist in c2 for item in sublist]
        network_df.loc[i] = [c[0],c[1],similarity_score(c1,c2)]

    return network_df
```

Running the above gives:

```
df_1946=func(df,1946)
df_1946.head()

Source    Target    Weight
Apple     Orange     0.6
Apple     Grape      0.3
Orange    Grape      0.7
```

I want to flatten the above to a single row:

```
       (Apple,Orange)  (Apple,Grape)  (Orange,Grape)  
1946        0.6             0.3            0.7
```

Note the above will not have 3 columns, but in fact around 5000 columns.

Eventually, I want to stack the transformed dataframe rows to get something like:

**df_all_years**

```
       (Apple,Orange)  (Apple,Grape)  (Orange,Grape)  
1946        0.6             0.3            0.7
1947        0.7             0.25           0.8
..
2015        0.75            0.3            0.65
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `(Apple,Orange)` - is it a string or a tuple?

Comment: Tuple. You can use anything you like, as long as there as is a way to tell what combination a particular cell represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rearrange the computation a bit differently. 
Instead of looping over the years:

```
for year in range(1946, 2015):
    partial_result = func(df, year)
```

and then concatenating the partial results, you can get 
better performance by doing as much work as possible on the whole DataFrame, `df`,
before calling `df.groupby(...)`. Also, if you can express the computation in terms of builtin aggregators such as `sum` and `count`, the computation can be done more quickly than if you use custom functions with `groupby/apply`.

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

def make_df():
    N = 10000
    df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': np.random.choice(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape'], size=N),
                       'grade': np.random.choice([1,2,3], p=[0.7,0.1,0.2], size=N),
                       'year': np.random.choice(range(1946,1950), size=N)})
    df['manufacturer'] = (df['year'].astype(str) + '-' 
                          + df.groupby(['year', 'fruit'])['fruit'].cumcount().astype(str))
    df = df.sort_values(by=['year'])
    return df

def similarity_score(df):
    """
    Compute the score between each pair of columns in df
    """
    agreements = {}
    disagreements = {}
    for col in IT.combinations(df,2):
        fruit1 = df[col[0]].values
        fruit2 = df[col[1]].values
        agreements[col] = ( ( (fruit1 == 1) & (fruit2 == 1) )
                            | ( (fruit1 == 3) & (fruit2 == 3) ))
        disagreements[col] = ( ( (fruit1 == 1) & (fruit2 == 3) ) 
                               | ( (fruit1 == 3) & (fruit2 == 1) ))
    agreements = pd.DataFrame(agreements, index=df.index)
    disagreements = pd.DataFrame(disagreements, index=df.index)
    numerator = agreements.astype(int)-disagreements.astype(int)
    grouped = numerator.groupby(level='year')
    total = grouped.sum()
    count = grouped.count()
    score = ((total/count) + 1)/2
    return score

df = make_df()
df2 = df.set_index(['year','fruit','manufacturer'])['grade'].unstack(['fruit'])
df2 = df2.dropna(axis=0, how="any")

print(similarity_score(df2))
```

yields

```
         Grape    Orange          
         Apple     Apple     Grape
year                              
1946  0.629111  0.650426  0.641900
1947  0.644388  0.639344  0.633039
1948  0.613117  0.630566  0.616727
1949  0.634176  0.635379  0.637786
```

Comment: I have edited the question and defined both df and func so that you can get a better idea of what is going on. Happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing a pandas routine to pivot the table in the way you refer to; while it handles ~5,000 columns--as resulting combinatorially from two initially separate classes--quickly enough (bottleneck step took about 20 s on my quad-core MacBook), for much larger scaling there are definitely faster strategies. The data in this example is pretty sparse (5K columns, with 5K random samples from 70 rows of years [1947-2016]) so execution time might be some seconds longer with a fuller dataframe.

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random  # using python3 .choices()
import re

# Make bivariate data w/ 5000 total combinations (1000x5 categories)
# Also choose 5,000 randomly; some combinations may have >1 values or NaN
random_sample_data = np.array(
    [random.choices(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Lemon', 'Lime'] +
                    ['of Fruit' + str(i) for i in range(1000)],
                    k=5000),
     random.choices(['Grapes', 'Are Purple', 'And Make Wine',
                     'From the Yeast', 'That Love Sugar'],
                    k=5000),
     [random.random() for _ in range(5000)]]
).T
df = pd.DataFrame(random_sample_data, columns=[
                  "Source", "Target", "Weight"])
df['Year'] = random.choices(range(1947, 2017), k=df.shape[0])

# Three views of resulting df in jupyter notebook:
df
df[df.Year == 1947]
df.groupby(["Source", "Target"]).count().unstack()
```

[image]

To flatten the grouped-by-year data, since groupby requires a function to be applied, you can use a temporary df intermediary to:

1. push all `data.groupby("Year")` into individual rows but with separate dataframes per the two columns "Target" + "Source" (to later expand by) plus "Weight".
2. Use `zip` and `pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product` to create an empty properly shaped pivot df which will be the final table, arising from temp_df.

e.g.,

```
df_temp = df.groupby("Year").apply(
    lambda s: pd.DataFrame([(s.Target, s.Source, s.Weight)],
                           columns=["Target", "Source", "Weight"])
).sort_index()
df_temp.index = df_temp.index.droplevel(1)  # reduce MultiIndex to 1-d

# Predetermine all possible pairwise column category combinations
product_ts = [*zip(*(pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product(
    [df.Target.unique(), df.Source.unique()])
))]

ts_combinations = [str(x + ' ' + y) for (x, y) in product_ts]

ts_combinations
```

[image]

Finally, use simple for-for nested iteration (again, not the fastest, though `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` might help speed things up, as shown). Because of the random sampling with replacement I had to handle multiple values, so you probably would want to remove the conditional below the second for loop, which is the step where the three separate dataframes are, for each year, accordingly zipped into a single row of all cells via the pivoted ("Weight") x ("Target"-"Source") relation.

```
df_pivot = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((70, 5000)),
                        columns=ts_combinations)
df_pivot.index = df_temp.index

for year, values in df_temp.iterrows():

    for (target, source, weight) in zip(*values):

        bivar_pair = str(target + ' ' + source)
        curr_weight = df_pivot.loc[year, bivar_pair]

        if curr_weight == 0.0:
            df_pivot.loc[year, bivar_pair] = [weight] 
        # append additional values if encountered 
        elif type(curr_weight) == list:
            df_pivot.loc[year, bivar_pair] = str(curr_weight +
                                                 [weight])
```

[image]

```
# Spotcheck:
# Verifies matching data in pivoted table vs. original for Target+Source
# combination "And Make Wine of Fruit614" across all 70 years 1947-2016
df
df_pivot['And Make Wine of Fruit614']
df[(df.Year == 1947) & (df.Target == 'And Make Wine') & (df.Source == 'of Fruit614')]
```